# fatal errors encountered -cannot continue (installing PHP for apache on Unix)

Tags: php, apache, freebsd

I am new to unix and I am trying to install PHP for Apache. When I run the `make install clean` command, I get these errors:
Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 1779: Malformed conditional (defined(USE_RC_SUBR) && ${USE_RC_SUBR:tu} != "YES")
Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.sites.mk", line 957: Malformed conditional (!empty(_PERL_CPAN_ID) && ${_PERL_CPAN_FLAG:tl} == "cpan")
Unknown modifier 't'

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 2948: Unclosed conditional/for loop
"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 2948: Unexpected end of file in for loop.

"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 6728: Unclosed conditional/for loop
"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 6728: Unexpected end of file in for loop.

make: fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to update FreeBSD.

Check your version of FreeBSD like so:

```
$ uname -a
```

And look for it here in the list of unsupported versions:

http://www.freebsd.org/security/unsupported.html

...and if you are on an unsupported version, update it:

More info here: https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=46310&p=259509

Comment: Hey Dave,i checked the version and its 8.2 and i am trying to update it but i would like to know if the update would drastically affect any settings or files as i do not want to alter any settings made on the server.

Comment: Just came back after many months.  I assume you got this sorted out by now.  If you still need help, let me know.